# Get session using javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, session

The cookies can get by javascript if we use document.javascript.

I want to know : get session($_SESSION["session_var_name"]) by javascript () ?????

Comment: Only the session id is kept in the cookie

Comment: Good reply !!

I have a question : Can any hacker get a session value using session id ??

Comment: What specific entity do you need to get from the $_SESSION variable to the browser?

Comment: @David no, the value is stored on the server. A hacker could steal your session id and identify as you on a website

Comment: @Matt H : Sorry!! I did not understand your question ^^

Comment: @Teneff : Is this code safe??


<?php
 // this vars saved from the login page : 

$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION["user"]);

$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION["pass"]);

// Check : 

$sql = mysql_query("select * from users where user = '$username' and pass = '$password' limit 1 ");

if (mysql_num_rows($sql)){
       echo 'Hi !!';
}
?>

Answer (score 6):

You can't. The data stored in the PHP `$_SESSION` super global is server-side only.

> The cookies can get by javascript if we use document.javascript.

FYI, it's [`document.cookie`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Document.cookie)

Answer (score 2):

If you need any value from the `$_SESSION` array, you **must** pass it.

example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var session_var_name = "<?=$_SESSION['var_name']?>";
</script>
```

you could also do it like this, BUT is really **BAD** practice:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // try this only at home :)
    var session = <?= json_encode($_SESSION) ?>;
</script>
```